# HTMLparser class not working in iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, parsing, domdocument, html-parsing

I am trying to convert string containing HTML data to html tags. 
I tried using HTMLParser for which i included libxml2, libxml2.2 frameworks but the framework doesn't extract to any class. Hence the class HTMLparser is not declared.

```
HTMLparser *htmlParser = [[[HTMLparser alloc] init] autorelease];
```

I also tried the following code

```
DOMDocument *document = [self DOMDocumentFromHTML: currentElementValue];
```

and

```
NSXMLDocument * doc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc]initWithXMLString: htmlString
                                        options: NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML
                                          error: &error];
```

But i face the same problem. The classes are not declared. And i cannot use the NSScanner class for i need to extract content from the HTML content. Can someone help me in knowing how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You trying the code for iPhone? ;) NSXMLDocument, HTMLParser, DOMDocument are available in MAC OS not in iPhone OS

Comment: okay then. what can we use to parse data for iPhone? what class can we use?